# Xamarin.Android MPAndroidChart c# version RoundBarChart

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

Im currently using [MPAndroidChart in C# via Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.1).

I tried to build a RoundedBarChart using this reference [WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart/blob/f940a527418aa0b695cd4f7fdf8b07922317cb17/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java)

But the issue some methods/variables for example:

In this line `setBarSpace` is existing. refer [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart/blob/f940a527418aa0b695cd4f7fdf8b07922317cb17/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java#L116)

```java
// initialize the buffer
    BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
    buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
    buffer.setBarSpace(dataSet.getBarSpace());
    buffer.setDataSet(index);
    buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));
```

while in c# [MPAndroidChart in C# via Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.1)

```
  // initialize the buffer
        BarBuffer buffer = BarBuffers[index];
        buffer.SetPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
        ///buffer.Bar(dataSet.getBarSpace());
        buffer.SetDataSet(index);
        buffer.SetInverted(Chart.IsInverted(dataSet.AxisDependency));
```

There is no `BarSpace` variable or method that is existing.
The java and c# version is the same `3.0.2`

If I am missing something kindly provide me insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [MPAndroidChart in C# via Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.1) is different from the [WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart/blob/f940a527418aa0b695cd4f7fdf8b07922317cb17/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java#L116).

The [MPAndroidChart.Xamarin](https://github.com/montecillodavidacn/MPAndroidChart.Xamarin) nuget you are using  is a `Xamarin.Android` binding for [MPAndroidChart by Philipp Jahoda](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). So you should refer to this [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample).

> There is no BarSpace variable or method that is existing.

You could use `buffer.SetBarWidth()` method, usage like this :

```
protected IBarDataProvider mChart;

...

buffer.SetBarWidth(mChart.BarData.BarWidth);
```

You could refer to [BarChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java#L140).

Comment: Actually your answer is right, But unfortunately I have to recover my time and do a fork and created a binding myself.